# How can escape $ in a foreach using php

Tags: php

The thing is I'm using a RestAPI to show films but how can a retrieve the convent of "gd$etag"?

```
foreach ($movies->feed->entry as $key => $value) {
    echo "<iframe id='player' type='text/html' width='640' height='390'
    src=" . $value->content->src. "
    frameborder='0'></iframe>";

 var_dump($value->gd$etag);
}
```

I've receiving a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$etag' (T_VARIABLE) i

Comment: This should work: `src='" . $value->content->src. "'`

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
$value->{'gd$etag'}
```